# Do you advise clients to use JSON or XML? And Why?

Tags: android, json, xml-parsing

Many times my client ask me whether they will deliver data via XML feed or JSON strings. I usually say:

- XML if you already have a feed and do not have a web developer who will create script for generating JSON strings
- JSON if you do not have any feed and need to create any from the scratch

What do you say? Do you think that delivering data via XML feeds is obsolete and that XML is over-complicated and too heavy?

Should I advise all clients (for the sake of the future) to move onto JSON way of delivering data?

**EDIT**

From another discussion https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2636245/choosing-between-json-and-xml I can see that JSON is advised for web services, which is the most used case scenario in my clients. It seems that I was advising them properly.

1. What is they want to pass news articles onto a mobile device - shall I advise XML of JSON?
2. What about post&get cases when I need to post some data and the to get the response which will be displayed on user's mobile device - XML or JSON?

Comment: XMl support features which are not fully available in JSON: for example XML Schema, Relax NG. Aditionally, various external tools like Model Frameworks (Eclipse EMF) relly on XML. So it realy depends on your needs and is not that easy.

Comment: @theomega Why do you suggest clients when they have none? And they're usually small to medium businesses.

Comment: thats up to you, depends on your usecase.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the consumers are browsers or mobile devices, I would recommend JSON.

1. Faster
2. Lighter
3. Native parsing support

If the consumers are other programs, I would recommend XML

1. Can be validated easily
2. Code generators available to make programming easy and is less error-prone

Comment: POST & GET shouldn't play a role. For HTTP, both XML & JSON are not very different, except for the mime type. I can't think of a reason that payload being HTML(for news article) can become a differentiating factor for choosing between XML & JSON.

Answer (score 1):

JSON - if you have a choice :)  Google GSON is a serious help there.

Comment: Indeed GSON is very powerful!

Comment: Simpler to develop with GSON than with XML.

Answer (score 1):

We Use JSON: If we want to serialize a data structure that’s not too text-heavy and all you want is for the receiver to get the same data structure with minimal effort

We use XML:If we want to provide general-purpose data that the receiver might want to do unforeseen weird and crazy things with, or if you want to be really paranoid and picky about i18n, or if what you’re sending is more like a document than a struct, or if the order of the data matters, or if the data is potentially long-lived.

This [discussed topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2636245/choosing-between-json-and-xml)  might help you .

Comment: A good part from the link you provided: "JSON for web services answering in-browser callbacks, and XML for, well, XML for when, well, hmmm. :-)"

Answer (score 1):

I agree with all the other recommendations for JSON, but for me the main reason for going with JSON is it's far easier to process on the server especially if you are using a language that supports the JSON structure natively (e.g NodeJS or Python).

I would not say XML is obsolete though. The one obvious case where XML wins is readability. As a programmer I would say JSON is just as readable but I've worked with a lot of people (mainly web designer types) who prefer the look and feel of XML, probably because they are already intimately familiar with HTML.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with your assessment really.  Json is easier (for a human) to read, more intuitive and lightweight.  XML is better if you have lots of existing XML solutions/interfaces that you're plugging in to.  I see XML as the established, mature heavyweight of structured documents, but you don't always need an established, mature heavyweight.  It all depends on the use case.